# Grouping and building objects in one statement

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code, I have a list of objects `Line` which represent orders. Because an order can have more than one product, I can group these objects by order number. The below code groups all the line objects by order number and I create an instance of the object called `ServiceOrder`. `ServiceOrder` has the order number and I bind all the products for that order to the `List<Line>`.

In my code, it's a 2 step process, I first group all the `Line` objects, then I iterate over the group to create a `List<ServiceOrder>` objects.

Using linq, can this be done with 1 line statement e.g. one step?

**Output**

```
Order: A1234
1. Widget 2
2. Sproket 2
3. Wobble 2
```

**Code:**

```
Line o1 = new Line { OrderNumber = "A1234", Description = "Widget", Qty = 2 };
Line o2 = new Line { OrderNumber = "A1234", Description = "Sproket", Qty = 2 };
Line o3 = new Line { OrderNumber = "A1234", Description = "Wobble", Qty = 2 };
Line o4 = new Line { OrderNumber = "A98745", Description = "Cog", Qty = 2 };
List<Line> incomingOrders = new List<Line>();
incomingOrders.Add(o1);
incomingOrders.Add(o2);
incomingOrders.Add(o3);
incomingOrders.Add(o4);

List<ServiceOrder> serviceOrders = new List<ServiceOrder>();

var orderGrouped = incomingOrders.Select((value, index) => new { obj = value, idx = index })
                 .GroupBy(order => order.obj.OrderNumber).Select(grp => grp.Select(g => g.obj).ToList()).ToList();

foreach (var grp in orderGrouped)
{
    ServiceOrder serviceOrder = new ServiceOrder();
    var firstOrder = grp.First();
    serviceOrder.OrderNumber = firstOrder.OrderNumber;                
    serviceOrder.Orders = grp;
    serviceOrders.Add(serviceOrder);

}


// print out
foreach (var order in serviceOrders) {

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Order: " + order.OrderNumber);
    int num = 1;
    foreach (var line in order.Orders) {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}. {1} {2}", num, line.Description, line.Qty));
        num++;
    }

}
```

```
public class ServiceOrder
{
    public List<Line> Orders { get; set; }      
    public String OrderNumber { get; set; }

}

public class Line {

    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The code is a small snippet of a much larger code. I threw this together because small workable examples are required. The index used in the real code. I have to ask you @MarcinJuraszek, the code makes no sense? really?

Comment: Sorry, that was too harsh.

Comment: Thanks :) - I know how it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IGrouping.Key` property:

```
List<ServiceOrder> serviceOrders =
    incomingOrders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderNumber)
                  .ToList(g => new ServiceOrder() {
                                       OrderNumber = g.Key,
                                       Orders = g.ToList() });
```

PS. Why are you introducing index into your enumeration when you're not using it later at all?